# Ziggy router modifying browser urls

Tags: laravel, apache, inertiajs

I'm in a bit of a pickle with Ziggy router.
I have a Laravel 10 + Vue 3 + Inertia + Vite app running on http://localhost/blender/public.

In my .env I have APP_URL and BASE_URL set to http://localhost/blender/public

When I output a route with route('dashboard') I get a correct route, which is defined in my /routes/web.php, and if I visit that route it works as expected.

Everything works fine, except the URL displayed in my browser, apparently it duplicates de base path, so my route /blender/public/dashboard is displayed as /blender/public/blender/public/dashboard. That value changes as soon as the page loads, so I guess is some JS changing the displayed URL.

I wouldn't mind but using Vue 3 + Inertia + Vite I want to take advantage of the reloading feature, but as soon as I make any changes, that messes up the route as it keeps appending the /blender/public value resulting in a 404 error.

To make things more confusing, I tried creating a .htaccess file at the root to get rid of the /public part of the route, this is it:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php
</IfModule>
```

If I do that and change APP_URL to simply http://localhost/blender and visit the site, I get a 404 | Not found, so I modified the 404 template to output url()->full() and I get http://localhost/blender. If I then set a prefix for all my routes using prefix('blender') it works.

So, here is my take on this problem:

- For some reason, Laravel 10 + Vue 3 + Inertia + Apache router is not recognizing the base url of the site
- I tried changing APP_URL and BASE_URL in my .env to different values (with/without the /blender) with no success
- Same base installation in my personal computer with macOS using nginx visiting blender.test works, company computer with Apache not working. I must use Apache since the target production server is Apache and can't do nothing about it
- I have several other Laravel 10 and 9 installations on that same computer without Vite + Inertia and routing works fine.
- If set the Apache DocumentRoot in httpd.conf to the folder containing my project, it works, so whatever is messing up my routes is the text after http://localhost

Anyway, after many days fighting this issue, I guess there is something in the Ziggy router provided with Laravel 10 + Vue 3 + Inertia installation and Apache that's causing the problem.

Any idea what it might be?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Not really.
I ended up defining in my .env a variable: 
`SITE_PREFIX="/whatever/your/path/is"`

In my routes I have
`Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->prefix(env('SITE_PREFIX'))->group(function () {`

Finally, in my vite.config.js I have: 
`export default defineConfig({
    base: '/whatever/your/path/is',`

This adds the prefix and solves the issue, but I don't get why this is happening.
I have a personal computer running macOS and everything works fine, but I' not using Apache there so...

Comment: Bundle of thanks.